# Serving a client side a component for my node module with a special file path

Tags: node.js

I'm building a NodeJS game engine. When the user creates an instance of the engine they must pass it an existing http server. The engine then attaches a socket server for updating the client side views.

What I'd like to do is serve a single JavaScript file at a special url that bridges the client side and allows the engine to setup its own sockets and provide the web page with a viewport and control binding api.

Is there anyway to add a request handler to an existing http server that can serve a single javascript based on the url?

I've tried this

```
function bindCoreFileServe(httpServer) {

    //create a server

    httpServer.on('request', function(req, res) {

        //check the url
        if(req.url === '/SliverJet.js') {

            //send the datafunction (req, res) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end('Hello World\n');

        }
    });
}
```

But it crashes node because the existing server also tries to send its own headers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out via the source of socket.io. Essentially I detach all of the event listeners from the httpServer and store them in an array then I bind my own listener to it. If the url doesn't belong to me I execute all of the detached event listeners with their call method passing it the httpServer as the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve that (attach 2 request handlers on the httpServer), but I suggest you take a different approach on this one.

For example, store all those URLs into the database and check for them using a wildcard, like so (this is for Express, but you get the idea):

```
app.get('/:db_url', function(req, res) {
  get_url_from_database(req.params.db_url, function (url, error) {
    if (error) { throw error; }
    else {
      // do things
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me looks like this:

```
function bindFileCoreServer (httpServer) {
  httpServer.addListener('request', function (req, res) {
    if (req.url === '/SliverJet.js') {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
      res.end('//Hello world!');
    }
  });
};
```

This is much simpler than storing the request listeners, replacing them, and then calling them in a loop if needed.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought one had to strip off the previous event listeners to stop them from handling the event if the url doesn't belong to them. Your method looks as though your event listener would be fired last.